# Blockarray superscript

Tags: amsmath, matrices, superscripts, blkarray

I am using `blkarray` to generate a labelled matrix. I would like to indicate the transpose of such matrix using a superscript with T. However I cannot find the right syntax to get what I want. Below you can find my attempts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
1 & & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
\begin{block}{(ccccccc)}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}^T
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{blockarray}{ccccccc}
1 & & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\
\begin{block}{(ccccccc)}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{block}^T
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{blockarray}{cccccccc}
1 & & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 &\\
\begin{block}{(ccccccc)c}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ^T\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the superscript nicely, as if the matrix was not generated with `blkarray`?

Comment: Yes, it should be a superscript to the closing bracket, same position that you get when applying a superscript to a `pmatrix` environment for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{blockarray}{cccccccc}
1 & & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 &\\
\begin{block}{(ccccccc)@{\hphantom{)}}l}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & {\vphantom{)}}^T\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! May I ask you what `\hphantom` and `\vphantom` do in the syntax?

Comment: @Francesco `\hphantom{)}` inserts an empty horizontal space/symbol that is as wide as `)`, and `\vphantom{)}` inserts and empty symbol that is as high as `)`.  You can put any symbol in the arguments of these phantoms. (There is alos `\phantom` which inserts an "empty" symbol.)

Comment: Thanks @marmot. So basically `\begin{block}{(ccccccc)@{\hphantom{)}}l}` indicates the beginning of a block with 7 centered elements enclosed by brackets followed by left-aligned element having the same horizontal width of `)`?

Comment: @Francesco Almost. `@{\hphantom{)}}l` says this is a left-aligned column with horizontal space as wide as `)` in the beginning.  You could also say `\begin{block}{(ccccccc)@{}l}
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & {\phantom{)}}^T\\
\end{block}` to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Set the indices using a smaller font:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \mbox{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{ *{7}{>{\centering}p{10pt}} }
      1 &  & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16
    \end{tabular}} \\
    \begin{tabular}{ *{7}{>{\centering}p{10pt}} }
      \makebox[0pt][r]{$\bigl($}%
      0 & $\cdots$ & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1%
      \makebox[0pt][l]{$\bigr)^T$}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

Above I use a `tabular` with fixed-width columns, setting elements inside `p{10pt}` columns. You can use zero-width boxes in the outer-columns to simulate a matrix-style `(`...`)^T`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `blockarray` at all?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\IND}[2]{\overset{#2\vphantom{\smash[t]{\Big|}}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\bigl(\IND{0}{1} \quad \cdots \quad \IND{0}{12} \quad
\IND{1}{13} \quad \IND{1}{14} \quad \IND{1}{15} \quad \IND{1}{16}\bigr)^T
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\IND}[2]{%
  \vbox{\ialign{%
    \hfil$##$\hfil\cr
    \scriptstyle#2\cr
    #1\cr
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\bigl(\IND{0}{1} \quad \cdots \quad \IND{0}{12} \quad
\IND{1}{13} \quad \IND{1}{14} \quad \IND{1}{15} \quad \IND{1}{16}\bigr)^T
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]